# Convert non-binary value into binary value?

Tags: classification, data-mining, dataset

I'm kind of a newbie in ML

I have a dataset like:

```
282,4,1,1,0,0,1,1,41,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,8,4
282,5,1,1,0,1,1,2,41,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,2,0,12,4
161,5,2,1,0,0,1,1,41,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,4,0,3,5
282,4,2,1,0,32,1,3,41,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,4,1
0,3,1,1,0,32,1,1,32,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,8,4
0,4,2,5,0,0,1,1,32,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,5
....
```

With output is the last column, it has 6 outputs `{A,B,C,D,E,F}` reference to `{0,1,2,3,4,5}`. I'm using NN and SVM(C-SVC, NuSVC) for training this dataset, but the accuracy still low (>60%).

I want to try something else to improve the performance of current results so I plan to train 6 binary models like `{A, not_A}`, `{B, not_B}`...

Should I only change the output into binary and keep all features for training?

Or I need to change all features into binary too? If yes, can you give a short explanation for me?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

**What I understood from your question is, for your OneVsAll classifiers, is it ok to convert feature set in to binary or not?**

> If this is correct, you should not convert your features into binary.
>   From the shared data set, it seems you have continuous data set and if
>   you convert into binary one, it will become categorical data, which
>   will have different model representation. So according to me you
>   should consume your data as it's. Though you can perform data
>   normalization.
>
> **Note: Multinominal Logistic Regression works on the similar principal
>   i.e. OneVsAll. So you can try this one as well.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will think about your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation of the target value into a binary label does not mean you should transform your features into binary ones.

On the other hand, what values can the features take? Based on that, you can think of ways to work with features to create new features or adjust them to serve better the algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will think about remapping the feature values.